# How set MariaDB to MAMP

Tags: macos, mariadb, mamp

i installed MAMP (Mac OS) and then I installed "brew install mariadb@10.1". The installation was successful. But know i don't know, how i can set mariadb as default db in MAMP.

I try edited file startMysql.sh, but not unsuccessfully. Do you have experiences with this problem?

Thanks for your responds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure MAMP to use mariadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448883/configure-mamp-to-use-mariadb)

Comment: I tried it but, but without results. :(